# Можно ли убрать пароль windows из-под Linux

Tags: windows-7, пароль, linux

Привет, знатоки. Вот такой вот вопрос, можно ли это осуществить. Ушел человек с работы, ПК запаролен, где человек никто не знает, а компьютер нужен.

win7, ПК подключен к сети.

Comment: Я пользоваться Offline NT Password Editor. Это специальная сборка линукса, которая умеет сбрасывать и изменять пароли.

Answer (score 5):

Делается так.

Перезагружаетесь с диска Live CD (например, Ubuntu). Монтируете жесткий диск с Windows

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows –o force
```

Переходите в системную папку Windows

```
cd /mnt/windows/Windows/System32/config
```

И запускаете команду на изменение пароля пользователя

```
chntpw –u someone SAM
```

И устанавливаете новый пароль. После этого перезагружаетесь, и входите в систему по обновленному паролю. При необходимости, чтобы получить полный список имен на машине, используете

```
chntpw –l SAM
```

Нужно иметь в виду, что при наличии зашифрованных папок на диске, они станут недоступными после изменения пароля.

Comment: chntpw –l SAMchntpw version 0.99.6 080526 (sixtyfour), (c) Petter N HagenopenHive(–l) failed: No such file or directory, trying read-onlyopenHive(–l) in fallback RO-mode failed: No such file or directoryclosing hive –lUnable to open/read a hive, exiting..не робит...

Comment: Я как понял доступа нет

Comment: Это из под sudo надо делать.

Comment: так в лайв сд судо по умолчанию, это само собой)))

Answer (score 0):

Почему только из под Линукс? Есть такое LiveCD (RusLive Full) и там есть утилита PassWordRenew - всегда выручала.

Comment: Потому, что я нахожусь там, где нет доступа к нету без этого компа, который запаролен) Можно считать что он роутер, а с телефона качать фалы... ну нереально, да и записать их на диск=флешку нет возможности

Comment: Если память не изменяет-opencrack!Катаем на сд или флеш,и стартуем как live.

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще отличная вещь -загрузиться с live-cd pogostick. Подробная [инструкция](http://www.windxp.com.ru/delpas.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы сбросить пароль, необходимо загрузить систему в режиме восстановления.

Итак, необходимо выполнить следующие шаги:

1. Загрузиться с установочного диска
2. Войти в меню «восстановление системы» и выбрать пункт «командная строка»
3. В командной строке, необходимо переименовать название утилиты специальных возможностей в cmd.exe, при этом сохранив все оригинальные файлы:

cd /d D:\

cd Windows\System32

move Utilman.exe Utilman.exe.original

copy cmd.exe Utilman.exe

После выполнения этих действий программа запуска специальных возможностей заменена на командную строку (Командная строка запускается от имени системы, что дает нам возможность изменять пароли локальных учетных записей).

5. перезагрузить ПК и снова загрузиться с диска
6. запустить «специальные возможности» (запустится командная строка)
7. Сменить пароль командой net user  pass
8. После смены пароля, загрузится с диска заменить переименованные файлы оригинальными.